# Codenameone Occasionaly see ConnectException when connecting to domain name url

Tags: codenameone

I have a domain name www.example.com with an ip address of 1.2.3.4

In my code I connect to https://www.example.com:8443 to call some REST services. (Ip address is never used) This all works fine but SOMETIMES I get a :

```
Exception: java.net.ConnectException - Failed to connect to 
www.example.com/1.2.3.4:8443
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to www.example.com/1.2.3.4:8443 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:1418)
at   com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:1368)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:219)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:142)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:104)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:325)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:470)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:547)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
    at com.codename1.impl.android.f.J(AndroidImplementation.java:5614)
    at com.codename1.l.g.j(ConnectionRequest.java:773)
    at com.codename1.l.s$c.run(NetworkManager.java:325)
    at com.codename1.impl.b$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Problem : sometimes the ip address (1.2.3.4) seems to be suffixed to the domain name resulting in an invalid url to connect to and hence the exception.  This does not happen all the time.

Any idea what could be causing this mangling of the url ?

From browser on device :
No Wifi and No Mobile Network : Cannot connect
With Wifi but No Mobile Network : Can connect
No Wifi but with Mobile Network : Can connect

Comment: Can you provide the source code of the connection logic?

Comment: As requested : 

`ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest(); cr.setPost(false); cr.setHttpMethod("GET"); cr.setUrl("https://www.myexample.com:8443/rest/endpoint"); cr.addArgument("var1", val1); cr.addArgument("var2", val2); cr.addResponseListener(callback); NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(cr); `

It only seems to happen when the app on the device is connected to a mobile data network. Don't think I have seen the error when on wifi.

Comment: Is it possible you associated the domain with an IP that is visible only within the NAT? 
If you try to access the URL from a browser while the device is disconnected from wifi does it work?

Comment: Updated original question. Don't think that is the case. (Just the web hosting company has DNS entries that point the domain name to my Amazon AWS instance ip.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address isn't actually suffixed, the Android exception just lists it in a confusing way since this is failing in the stage of connecting to the server. It lists the IP its trying to open. After the server is connected the get request for the actual url is made, but that stage wasn't reached yet.

I'm not sure why the failure occurs some times and doesn't occur on others but wireless networks are unreliable so that might have something to do with it.

Comment: I had another look at our code and noticed I had `setDefaultCacheMode(CachingMode.SMART);` I changed this to `setDefaultCacheMode(CachingMode.OFF);` and I have not seen the error again. As I don't know about the internals of this call, could there be a reason why this is causing an issue ?

Comment: I don't see any connection between caching mode and this issue. It just adds HTTP headers for `If-Modified-Since`, `If-None-Match` etc.